# How can I check the reponse of a jquery post for spacific result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm sending a value to another page. If there is results from a sql query I want to display in an overlay. If there is no results do not display the overlay.

What's happening is that the overlay pops up whether there are results or not. I'm new to this style of version of posting with jquery. I'm used to 'spelling it out' via `$.ajax({});` or plain php.

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#signup").overlay();

    $('#status').change(function() 
    {
        whoclock=$('#associate').val();
        $.post("ckrd_messsys.php",{asso:whoclock},function(result)
        {
            if(result) 
            {
                $("#signup").overlay().load();
                $("#signup").overlay({mask: '#999', fixed: false,load:true});
                $("#spellout").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#confirm").click(function() 
    {
        $.post("ckrd_messsys.php",{asso:whoclock,confirmread:"Y"},function(result)
        {
            $("#signup").overlay().close();
        });
    });
});
```

This is my php:

```
$asso = $_REQUEST['asso'];
$confirmread = $_REQUEST['confirmread'];
$getmess = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `file` FROM `foo` WHERE `empl`='".$asso."' ORDER BY `id` ASC",$con));

if($asso != "")
{
    if(file_exists("message/".$getmess[0].".txt"))
    {
        $txtfile = fopen("message/".$getmess[0].".txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
        $readIT=fgets($txtfile);
        echo $readIT;
        fclose($txtfile);
    }
 }
```

If there is no txt file I do not want the overlay to load. How do I tell the jquery there is no 'file' or 'result' and not to load?? (Sorry for all the edits....just seems I'm not getting the answers/help I'm after.)

Can I just simply add to my php page:

```
else
{
echo "NOTHING";
}
```

Then change my jquery to something like:

```
if(result != "NOTHING") 
{
....
}
```

I've tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I got some observations:

**1.** I never used before that `overlay` plugin but seems like the `load` property fires the `overlay` if `true` so there is no need to put at first `$(selector).overlay()` and later invoke `$(selector).overlay().load()` It doesn't make sense if you specify the property at first.

**2.** I think will be good to check the `callback` response `object` (`result`). Sometimes, when implementing a `rest` or something else, you can return `JSON`, `XML`, `string`, `html`, etc but in general it is supposed that `result` is a `javascript` object, something similar to this:

`Object: {}` *(if empty)* or `Object: {name: 'Oscar'}` *(with data)*

So, I think what you are checking when doing your conditional `if(result) { ... }` is to determine if the variable is `false` or `undefined` but you are not considering if its `empty` or not *AND!* when evaluating an `Object: {}` as your `result` variable, it will pass the condition as *"true"*.

What you can do is using the `$.isEmptyObject` function from `jQuery` when evaluating your `Object` as the following code I've implemented for testing.

---

*Check this out.*

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/34m2R/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="signup">
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Make ajax call (no results)"/>
    <input class="btn" data-type="wr" type="button" value="Make ajax call (with results)"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    /* In this case, this is the function that replaces 
     * your on 'change' event handler 
     */
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        makeAjaxCall(type);
    });

});

/* This makes the ajax calls. 
 * @param {type} if 'wr' will add some extra 
 * data to the response obj.
 */
function makeAjaxCall(type) {
    $.post('/echo/json', function(data) {        
        if(type === 'wr') { // wr: simulate data with results
            data.name = 'Oscar';
        }
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            makeOverlay($('#signup'), data);
        }
    }).fail(function(r) { // ajax call failed (you can test this by replacing URL)
        var code = r.status;
        var error = r.statusText;
        alert('Error: ' + code + ', ' + error);
    });
}

/* This will make the overlay with 
 * predefined cfg.
 * @param {elem} affected element
 * @param {data} callback response object
 */
function makeOverlay(elem, data) {
    var cfg = { 
        mask: '#ccc',
        load: true
    };
    elem.overlay(cfg);
    elem.html('<b>Hello ' + data.name + '!</b>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and observations. I figured it had something to do with it not being `empty`. Is there a simple way to post a php variable that I can then check for in my jquery? Something like `echo $dontDoIt;` and look for that? Then something like: `if($dontDoIt != "yes"){.....}

Comment: doesn't your example just repeat back `data.name = 'Oscar';`? (Again...I'm a newbie.) What about getting results not known yet? Like my previous comment....

Comment: That php data cames from your ajax callback or is it something you want to use it under javascript and you already have it on php context?

Comment: I have (or can add) a variable to my `ckrd_messsys.php` page to provide a result to send back to my jquery. I just don't know how to get it there. Can I add something like `$heresResult = $_REQUEST['myresult'];` ?

Comment: You can do `<script type="text/javascript">var val = '<?php echo $variable ?>';</script>` then use it.

Comment: Yes, adding that or anything to the `ckrd_messsys.php` page I'm ok on. It's how to tie it into my jquery as an 'if then' statement. Back to my original question...I can send data to the other page, I just can't get it back in a useable form.(Like to use in php...)

Comment: try using this: `<script type="text/javascript"> val = '<?php echo $variable ?>';</script>` (there is no `var` as you can see, this will declare it as a global variable) and after that make your other `js` imports like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>`, then try printing the `val` variable in some function under your other file(s).

Comment: I just updated my question with the page I'm sending data to. Is there not a simple code like php that will send something to the original page??

Answer (score 0):

You probably always have a result object from the response, just with different properties.

I usually always return the json property success=true. Then I check:
if(response.success===true) { }

Why not add debugger; in the javascript and check the result object in your browser?

Comment: I was guessing that there would always be some kind of response. Is there a way to filter or ask for a specific value? I'm still trying to understand how to get a specified value back. Any tutorials I find are SO general.

Comment: Well, what is your server side language? In C# you would write something like: return Json(new { success = true });

Comment: The page I'm posting to (php) checks to see if a file (txt) exists then echo's the results. These results are then displayed in the above mentioned overlay. If there is no file I want the above overlay not to display.

Comment: So perhaps you should test: if(result!=='') { ... }
Again, add "debugger;" to the javascript and watch the variable in Chrome and you'll know for sure.

Comment: I used your suggestion of `!==` and still the overlay loads. I've never used the Chrome debugger, however, I tried (after reading up on it) and it seems to be simply sending back the data sent out. (Sending back the `asso:whoclock`information it was sent from the example above.)

Comment: I just added the page jquery would be posting to. How would I pull out the data from what I've got?